# OCaml guessing number game

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I've decided to do a simple exercise in OCaml, writing a guess the number application:

The solution I came up with was this:

```
let () = 
  let func_end = ref false in 
  while !func_end != true do
    let () = print_endline "Enter guess:" in
    let input = read_int () in
    let bound = 50 in 
    let random_number = Random.int bound in 
    if input == random_number then 
      let () = print_endline "Correct!" in
      func_end := true
  done
```

I wonder if there's a more functional approach to this problem,
the use of refs seems more imperative rather than functional.

Comment: Asking for advice and opinion is off-topic on SO. This is a better fit on [codereview.se]

Comment: `x != true` is usually spelled `not x`.

Comment: Beware that you should use `<>` instead of `!=` until you know the difference between both. Besides, `let () = something in ... ` can be written, more succinctly, `something; ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a while loop and a `ref` type, which are imperative features of OCaml, rather than functional, but you can approximate the functionality of this loop in a generalized functional way with recursion.

A while loop involves an initial state, a boolean predicate, and a body. We can pass these things to a function, with the predicate being a function which tests the state, and the body working on the state to generate a new state.

```
let rec do_while state pred body =
  if pred state then
    let state = body state in
    do_while state pred body
  else
    state
```

Consider a simple example of this:

```
utop # do_while 1 (fun x -> x < 10) (fun x -> Printf.printf "%d\n" x; x + 1);;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
- : int = 10
```

It can then be used to replace your loop. The state will be the correct number, and the guess. Of course, the guess won't exist on the first go around so we'll use a value of type `int option`. If the correct number and the guess are the same, the function will return `true` and the loop will end. Otherwise it will continue. The loop body function will prompt for input and update the state. It will also print an error message if the guess isn't correct.

```
let _ = 
  do_while 
    (Random.int 50, None) 
    (function 
     | (correct, Some guess) when correct = guess -> false 
     | _ -> true) 
    (fun (correct, _) -> 
      let () = print_endline "guess a number:" in
      let guess = read_int () in 
      (if correct <> guess then print_endline "Incorrect guess!";
       (correct, Some guess)))
```

As an aside, you do not need the `ref` type in your while loop. You can use an exception to exit the loop.

```
exception Exit

try
  while true do
    let () = print_endline "Enter guess:" in
    let input = read_int () in
    let bound = 50 in 
    let random_number = Random.int bound in 
    if input = random_number then raise Exit
  done
with 
| Exit -> ()
```

Comment: Thank you <3
Never thought about the question that way!
It's interesting how we can basically brake down the problem to 3 phases: 
Initial State, predicate and body.
Where did you learn this? Some book?

Comment: Experience. More years than I'd like to believe can have passed.

Answer (score 0):

The "functional loop" is recursion.

A good step would be to split this into functions; something like this, perhaps

```
let guess () = 
  let () = print_endline "Enter guess: " in 
  read_int()

let answer () = 
  Random.int 50

let rec play () = 
  if guess () = answer () then 
    print_endline "Correct!" 
  else 
    play ()
```

But I personally feel that it's a bit unfair to create a new correct answer for every guess, so you might want to stick to just one

```
let guess () = 
  let () = print_endline "Enter guess: " in 
  read_int()

let answer () = 
  Random.int 50

let play () = 
  let rec with_guess it = 
    if guess () = it then 
      print_endline "Correct!"
    else 
      with_guess it
  in 
  with_guess @@ answer ()
```

This can easily be extended to provide hints, such as "too high" or "too low".